# cruisecontrol mstest problem wenn tests fail

Tags: mstest, cruisecontrol

i use MSTest with CruiseControl. When I run my compile and tests and all tests pass then I can see the mstest results in my dashboard.

for example: 5 tests ran. 5 tests passed. 0 tests failed.

when tests fail I would expect to see something like this: 
5 tests ran. 1 failed. 4 passed.

but if one test fails I get this:
0 tests ran. 0 passed. 0 failed.

It looks like cruisecontrol has a display problem if tests fail.

bye bembi

Comment: it looks like cruisecontrol isn't processing the testresults file if mstest exits with return code != 0

Answer (score 0):

solved it.
i had to move the file merge block out of the task block and into a publishers block:

```
<project>
  ...
  <publishers>
    <merge>
      <files>          
        <file>C:\cc\mstestResult.trx</file>
      </files>
    </merge>
    <xmllogger />
  </publishers>      
</project>
```